# Image Panel that Displays Images Based on Spatial Extent in ArcGIS WebAppBuilder

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

Does anyone know of a way of possibly making a side panel in a webapp for ArcGIS Online that would allow images to be displayed that are either attached to point location data, or have a URL in the table. I would like to images to appear based on the current extent of the map and disappear when no longer in view on the map.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any widgets that would do this out-of-the-box, but I think it would be a great case to create a custom widget for use with [Web AppBuilder Developer Edition](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/).

As you start working with Web AppBuilder more, some other useful resources include the [GIS StackExchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-web-appbuilder), and the [Web AppBuilder Custom Widgets GeoNet Group](https://geonet.esri.com/groups/web-app-builder-custom-widgets).